# ERROR undefined, HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"

Tags: http, ionic4

i have a little worry, if some can just help me, i use a laravel 5.8 api, which i create, when i retrieve the parameter data mtr from posteman its walk, but when i do the same thing with this url << url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studentbyid/45' >> it works its problem because the 45 is the mtr, whereas according to the logic that I try to put in place and that it is the user who will introduce the mtr, then display...

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Candidate } from '../models/candidate';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate',
  templateUrl: './candidate.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate.page.scss'],
})
export class CandidatePage implements OnInit {
  mtr: '45';
  // tslint:disable-next-line: new-parens
  data: any;
  url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studentbyid/';

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ionViewWillEnter(mtr: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/' + this.mtr)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log(this.data);
        }, 
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
   }

  ngOnInit() {}

  getbyID( mtr: string) {}

}
```

here is the result in the console when I place it directly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghT6L.png)
and that's when I try to retrieve the word from a user[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStY0.png)

if there are some who can just help me, and I notice that there is no answer in the form of object

Comment: Did you get any solution for this..?? Please suggest me any idea please...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `mtr` is indeed undefined.

```js
mtr: '45';

console.log(mtr);
// undefined
```

You need to set the variable to the '45' string instead you typed the `mtr`variable as type '45'.

```js
mtr: string = '45';

console.log(mtr);
// '45'
```